# ConditionalOnProperties does not toggle an endpoint within a class with multiple endpoints Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, toggle, endpoint

I tried with the ConditionalOnProperties annotation for a particular endpoint within a class which has multiple endpoints. However, the condition doesn't seem to toggle it, but turn on always. It works well on the class level, but not on the endpoint level. Is it a bug?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/test", consumes = {"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
@ResponseBody
@Timed()
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "test.enabled")
public String test(@RequestParam(EXCEPTION_LOG_MESSAGE) String errorLog) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the annotation, it should be used for beans. Either for a method, which returns a `@Bean` or for a class, which is a `@Component`, `@Sevice` or –as in your case– a `@Controller`.

The method you are annotating does not define a bean but is just a method of a bean, which gets defined anyway.

To achieve you goal, you could for example

- put the specific endpoint to an extra `Controller` and annotated that one
- or use the `@Value` annotation to get the property and just add an `if` to you method which makes it return something like `404` in case the property is not set:

Example for the latter idea:

```
@Value("${test.enabled}")
private boolean testEnabled;

public ResponseEntity test() {
    if (!testEnabled) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
    // ...
}
```

There are probably more options.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I think the later one is the best solution for me. Wonder if you have the sample code that I can return the 404 error when the flag is false?